# Apply on multiple ids except some dynamic ids using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have elements with id such as: `#ids1`, `#ids2`, `#ids3`, `#ids4`, `#ids5` and so on.

I've used this jQuery selector, `$('id^="ids"').html('hello');` however it will apply to all ids, but I don't want to apply it to `#ids4`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:not()` to exclude a specific `id`:

```
$('[id^="ids"]:not(#ids4)').html('hello');
```

However, I'd strongly suggest using a common class that you apply to only the elements you do want to target instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use .not() method [https://api.jquery.com/not/]

something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[id^="ids"]').not('#ids4').html('hello all');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ids1">1</div>
<div id="ids2">2</div>
<div id="ids3">3</div>
<div id="ids4">4</div>
<div id="ids5">5</div>
```